# How can I secure my connection to MySql server

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, security, encryption

I've made a C# program that connects to MySql database, gets data and modifies it, everything works well.

But now I begin to care about my database security, so the problem is that the password is being sent in clear text form to the database:

```
ConnectionString = "SERVER=mysqlserver.com;DATABASE=databasename;UID=" + "touk" + ";PASSWORD=" + "xxxxxxx" + ";SslMode=Preferred;";
```

I wonder if sending my connection string like this is dangerous ?

It is a Windows Forms Application.
I manage a database with lists of objects. The clients are my friends that I know very well, so no chance that they play with.

The problem is that I would have no problems with other people who might enjoy a break into my server.
I'm using [freesqldatabase](http://freesqldatabase.com) as Hosting server, so all my clients will use the same user and password.

I'm using [MySQL.Data](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Mysql.Data/)

Comment: Explain more about your scenario. Do you have an executable you deploy at clients, that connect to your MySQL server? This is not the way to go. Expose data and operations through a web service for example, where you have more fine-grained control on what certain clients can and can't do with your database. You cannot securely encrypt a configuration file if you deploy it to the client, as the running application will also have to decrypt it in order to use it.

Comment: It is doubtful that MySQL sends the password in clear text form - http://www.pythian.com/blog/does-mysql-send-passwords-in-the-clear/. Also, do not ask many questions in one (SQL injections do not directly influence the process of storage and processing of the authentication information, and "all these things" are far too broad a definition). Read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/security-guidelines.html and other freely available guidelines, and then ask more specific questions.

Comment: @CodeCaster
Yes, it is an application WindowsForm exe I was sending some people over I manages a database with lists of objects. 
the cliens are my friends that I know very well, so no chance that they play with. 
the problem is that I would have no problems with other people who might enjoy a break into my server.

I'm using http://www.freesqldatabase.com/ as Hosting server, so all my clients will use the same user and password

Comment: @EugenePodskal
By "all these things" I mean, all the things that can happen if I send my password in clear.
I wonder if sending my connection string like this is dangerous.

Comment: @Touk MySQL uses something close [basic access authentication](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19525/help-understanding-basic-user-authentication-with-salts-and-hashing), so nothing is sent in clear text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear text passwords are never sent during the authentication in "MySql".
so it's not that dangerous. But exposing the database to the public isn't a recommended approach.
As CodeCaster first commented; you should expose your data through web services.
at this stage you can fully encrypt your communication channels.

Comment: What do you mean by "exposing the database to the public" ?

Comment: i mean allowing the database server to be accessed from the internet or the public network